# On Windows 10, is it possible to change the default font used for a regional language?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, language

First up, the current system fonts are all defaults - I haven't played around with Registry yet. My understanding from this [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) is that Windows has a default font for each language and in my case for Malayalam, it is 'Kartika'.

Problem is, that font sucks. From an aesthetic point of view at least. There are many combination letters in Malayalam (I guess Devanagiri and some other languages like German have those too) and those are not shown properly.

For example, in the picture below, the top one is how it should be ideally shown. Bottom one works too but isn't the intuitive (or beautiful) way to show it. I think this is a Font issue. This [**blog post**](https://blog.keyman.com/2015/03/working-through-malayalam-display-in-windows/) has some info on it but does not seem to have a solution.

Could someone help? I am happy with the default font for English - Malayalam is a different story though.

PS: I think Android handles this much better.

[image]

Comment: You can download fonts from internet, a simple search gave http://www.malayalamfont.com/ You have to download the required font, install and set as default for the language.

Comment: how do i do that last part?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you want to change the default font for a language? Do you mean the font the UI uses when that language is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [SMC Wiki](https://wiki.smc.org.in/%E0%B4%B8%E0%B4%B9%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%AF%E0%B4%82#Changing_Default_Font-family_Of_Windows_Operating_System):

**Changing Default Font-family Of Windows Operating System**

You can change the default font family of windows operating system for a better rendering of Malayalam fonts...

- Open settings.
- Click on Personalization.
- Click on fonts.
- Go to File > Export… to save the registry file somewhere on your hard drive.
- In order to change the font family, the font must be installed...
- Open Notepad and copy and paste the following into it:

> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
> "Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Black (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Black Italic (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Bold (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Bold Italic (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Historic (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Italic (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Light (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Light Italic (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Semibold (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Semibold Italic (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Semilight (TrueType)"=""
> "Segoe UI Semilight Italic (TrueType)"=""
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes]
> "Segoe UI"="Manjari"
> ```

Replace Manjari in the last line with the name of the font you want to use as your system default.

- Click File > Save.
- Change the "Save as" type to "All Files."
- In the File name field, give the file a .reg extension. You can name it anything, as long as it ends in .reg.
- Click Save.
- Double-click the registry file you just created to run it. You'll be prompted to allow the file to make changes to the computer and confirm you want to continue, then get confirmation the changes were successfully made.
- Restart your computer to see the font change applied across Windows.
  If you want to revert back the changes, open regedit and import the exported registry file mentioned in step 4.

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do this but eventually decided to not change the font.
Details here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Kerala/comments/ih5jud/malayalam_font_problems_on_windows_10/